# Matrix of Arrays

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix of arrays. So, I want an `a`-by-`b` matrix, where each element `M(i,j)` is actually a single column array. This would be the equivalent of a three-dimensional array in C.

The only solution I can see in Matlab, is by creating a three-dimensional matrix. However, the third dimension is yet another matrix, rather than a column array.

What's the solution?

Comment: Did you try cell arrays?

Comment: How are you creating the `three-dimensional array`? What is `C` here?

Answer (score 0):

3D matrix in Matlab may work very well, and you can extract the vectors like this:

```
M = ones(4,5,6);  % 4x5 matrix of 6-element vectors
V = M(2,3,:)      % the vector on position (2,3)
```

A more flexible solution, though with a tiny penalty in data access speed, would be a cell array:

```
M = repmat({ones(6,1)}, 4, 5);  % 4x5 cell array of 6-element vectors
V = M{2,3}                      % the vector on position (2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like CST-Link said, and you can add `squeeze()` :

```
M = randi(3, [4,5,6]);
v = squeeze(M(1,3,:))
```

Using cell array handles a 3rd dimension with variable length. But if they all have the same length, I would use a 3-D matrix (less memory overhead, and you can take a vector easily from any dimension).